# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' on line 2

Tags: php, html, mysql, deprecated

Can you help me guys to fix my error, I stack with this error message the problem is only when inserting data into database.

I don't know if my code is an old coding style.

I badly need your help guys sorry for my English.

```
<?php
if ($sID > 0) {
    $query = "UPDATE `shows`
       SET    video = '$video', 
       title = '$title', 
       description = '$description', 
       content = '$content', 
       episodes = '$episodes', 
       duration = '$duration', 
       pilot_rating = '$pilot_rating', 
       pilot_share = '$pilot_share', 
       sold_in = '$sold_in', 
       production = '$production', 
       marketing = '$marketing', 
       rating = '$rating', 
       awards = '$awards', 
       alias = '$alias', 
       publish = '$publish', 
       posted = '$posted', 
       `show` = '1', 
       catid2 = '$catID2', 
       catid = '$catID', 
       modified_date = '$modified_date', 
       modified_by = '".$_SESSION['cpuid']."', 
       now_available = '$now_available', 
       all_titles = '$all_titles', 
       hot_clips = '$hot_clips', 
       featured_program = '$featured_program' 
WHERE  sid = '$sID'";
} else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `shows`  ( video, title, description, content, episodes, duration, pilot_rating, pilot_share, sold_in, production, rating, awards, alias, publish, posted, show, catmain, catid2, catid, created_by, modified_date, modified_by, now_available, all_titles, hot_clips, featured_program )  VALUES  ('$video', '$title', '$description', '$content', '$episodes', '$duration', '$pilot_rating', '$pilot_share', '$sold_in', '$production', '$rating', '$awards', '$alias',  '$publish', '$posted', '1', '1',  '$catID2', '$catID', '".$_SESSION['cpuid']."', '$modified_date', '".$_SESSION['cpuid']."', '$now_available', '$all_titles', '$hot_clips', '$featured_program' )";
}
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Echo your `$query` and see what is wrong with it.

Comment: @u_mulder oh, you're right. I'm sorry. Will delete my comment.

Comment: so what is the proper way of coding on it?

Comment: You should use MySQLi instead of MySQL.

Comment: i change my whole website that uses mysql code ?

Comment: hi @u_mulder here is the echo my query:

Comment: Show is a reserved word. And see ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax

Comment: Yes. Change everything that uses mysql_ - and use prepared and bound statements